# ¿Como ordenar valor null o vació al ultimo de consulta Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Gracias de antemano por la gran ayuda, 
tengo la siguiente consulta, la cual los datos se ordenan de manera ascendente, actualmente los registros vacíos se colocan al principio del resultado, quiero encontrar la forma de colocar los valores nulos o vacíos al final del array (resultado). ¿Alguna sugerencia?

//BUSCA LIBROS:
 $libros = Libros::orderBy('autor', 'asc')->get();

Saludos.

Comment: Es una base de datos MySQL o Postgres o ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Si es Postgres le agregas a tu consulta:

```
ORDER BY NULLS LAST
```

En MySQL puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(autor), autor ASC;
```

Creo que necesitarás orderByRaw al crear tu consulta:

```
/**
 * Add a raw "order by" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  string  $sql
 * @param  array  $bindings
 * @return $this
 */
public function orderByRaw($sql, $bindings = [])
{
    $property = $this->unions ? 'unionOrders' : 'orders';

    $type = 'raw';

    $this->{$property}[] = compact('type', 'sql');

    $this->addBinding($bindings, 'order');

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Al indicar el campo pones un "-" delante, quedando algo así:

```
$libros = Libros::orderBy('-Libros.autor', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: excelente, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Complementando el comentario de arriba, a mí me funcionó de esta forma usando MySQL

```
 $libros = Libros::orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL('Libros.autor'))->get();
```